# Limit of $f'(x)$ when $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I was trying to prove the following proposition:

> If $f$ is differentiable and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=m\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=m$.

I tried with the mean value theorem but I gave up. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Since $f'(x)\to m$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $x_0$ such that $m-\epsilon< f'(x)<m +\epsilon$ whenever $x>x_0$.

From the mean value theorem, we have

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(\xi)(x-x_0)$$

for some $\xi \in (x_0,x)$.  But then we can write for $x>x_0$

$$\frac{f(x_0)}{x}+\left(1-\frac{x_0}{x}\right)(m -\epsilon)<\frac{f(x)}{x}<\frac{f(x_0)}{x}+\left(1-\frac{x_0}{x}\right)(m +\epsilon)$$

Letting $x\to \infty$ we see that for all $\epsilon>0$ we have

$$m -\epsilon<\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}<m +\epsilon$$

and hence $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=m$ as was to be shown!

Answer (score 2):

You could show it using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: But you haven't enough conditions...

Comment: @ÁngelaFlores Yes, you do. You do not need to assume $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Why? I always thought the limit had to be an undeterminated form

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2184203/462) is really just the standard proof of L'Hôpital's rule in this case. You should be able to extend it to the general case: If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)/g'(x)$ exists and equals, say, $L$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x)=L$.

Answer (score 1):

When we have $f'(x)=m+o(1)$ we can integrate it : $\quad f(x)=mx+C+o(x)$

Which is $\displaystyle{\frac{f(x)}{x}=m+\underbrace{\frac{C}{x}}_{\to\; 0}+o(1)}\quad$ or simply $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=m$.

**In fact Taylor expansions can be integrated because they are nothing more than inequalities**

As Dr. MV wrote this is $m-\varepsilon < f'(x) < m+\varepsilon$

Integrating it gives $\displaystyle{\int_{x_0}^{x}(m-\varepsilon)\;dt < \int_{x_0}^{x}f'(t)\;dt < \int_{x_0}^{x}(m+\varepsilon})\;dt$

$\implies(m-\varepsilon)(x-x_0)< f(x)-f(x_0) < (m+\varepsilon)(x-x_0)$

Regrouping $mx+(f(x_0)-mx_0)-(x-x_0)\varepsilon < f(x) < mx+(f(x_0)-mx_0)+(x-x_0)\varepsilon$

And you recognize $C=f(x_0)-mx_0$ and $(x-x_0)\varepsilon=o(x)$

Finally (abusing a little the notations) this is $mx+C-o(x) < f(x) < mx+C+o(x)$ and we arrive at the same conclusion.